# Multiple connections on a hapi server

Tags: hapi.js

I want to add plugins to a hapi server which has multiple connections like listening on different ips.

Is it possible to add a plugin to all servers configured?

Or how to loop over all servers to add the plugin to all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default plugins will add routes for all connections when calling `server.route()`.

To limit which connections the plugin adds routes to, you can use labels when creating connections and then specify those labels when registering plugins. Here's an example:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({ port: 8080, labels: 'a' });
server.connection({ port: 8081, labels: 'b' });
server.connection({ port: 8082, labels: 'c' });

var plugin1 = function (server, options, next) {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/plugin1',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('Hi from plugin 1');
        }
    });

    next();
};
plugin1.attributes = { name: 'plugin1' };

var plugin2 = function (server, options, next) {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/plugin2',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('Hi from plugin 2');
        }
    });

    next();
};
plugin2.attributes = { name: 'plugin2' };

server.register(plugin1, function (err) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.register(plugin2, { select : ['a'] }, function (err) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        server.start(function () {

            console.log('Server started');
        })
    });
});
```

**GET /plugin1** route from `plugin1` responds on :

```
http://localhost:8080/plugin1
http://localhost:8081/plugin1
http://localhost:8081/plugin2
```

where as **GET /plugin2** route from `plugin2` only responds on:

```
http://localhost:8080/plugin2
```

Comment: @matt_harrison how will stop single port(example 8082) on the server?

Comment: FYI. the `connection()` was removed in `v17`

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple `connections` in hapi to have multiple, internal servers available. The great thing about those separated servers: you can register plugins and routes individually only for the one that requires the functionality.

Find more details in this tutorial on [how to separate frontend and backend within a single hapi project](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-run-separate-frontend-and-backend-servers-within-one-project).

Hope that helps!